# How to embed a shinny app in a webpage (github.io, wordpress or jekyll)

Tags: wordpress, shiny

I am trying to find a way to embed my shiny apps to a website. I am sorry but I can't think of a reproducible example. Here is one of the apps I want to embed ig that is useful.

https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/WhereShouldYouLive/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe an iframe?

```
<iframe src="https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/WhereShouldYouLive/" style="border:none;width:1000px;height:500px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy I will try that